# New Google Sites API

Tags: google-sites-2016

I know the current Google Sites API only supports Classic Sites.

**Does this API exist now?** and **How to manage(create and etc) New Google Sites though API?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check [Google sites api](https://developers.google.com/sites) at the very top of the page it states.

[image]

If there was an api for accessing the new version they would have stated it.  There is not.

Answer (score 2):

No, an API doesn't exist.

There are several feature requests in the issuetracker.google.com site, so they are aware it is needed. You would think they have some of the framework developed, since there is currently some access to sites (and I don't mean for editing) through the existing drive API. It would be worth adding your comments to those requests in the issue tracker website.

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36761330
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/7324991
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120462223
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/205856782

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Though Google Sites API is still not available, I discovered some good news (for my use case, at least). I can confirm there are some minimal Google Sites abilities available through the Google Drive API. Specifically, I was able to add a user to the my site as viewer to a published site, using the Drive API permissions. Here is the Python code.

```py
# get boilerplate creds= code from here https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/python

drive = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

new_permission = {
    'type':'user', 
    'role':'reader',
    'view':'published', 
    'emailAddress':USER_EMAIL
    }

# you can get the SITE_FILEID from the site url
res = drive.permissions().create(fileId=SITE_FILEID, body=new_permission).execute()
```

Since the OP specifically asked about create, that works like so:

```py
new_file = {
    'name':'test site2',
    'mimeType':'application/vnd.google-apps.site',
    }

res = drive.files().create(body=new_file).execute()
```

Hope this can help some folks.

Answer (score 0):

According to this question, Google planned the new API for Google Sites for end of 2021: https://support.google.com/sites/thread/3363462/is-there-any-eta-for-the-new-google-sites-api?hl=en

I did not hear any news, since that.